# Vertical Text \pstPlanePut

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I'm trying do write some vertical text, with the basis line parallel to the z-axis, in the xz-plane...

Here is what I got, and I want the vertical text to be parallel to the z-axis.

[image: MME]

Is it possible with an equivalent of the option `planecorr=xyrot`, but for other planes (like the xz plane in my case) ? Or just a trick to do it, it's fine...

Here is the code I used :

```
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(2,3)
   \pstThreeDCoor[IIIDticks,xMin=-1,yMin=-1,zMin=-1,zMax=2]
   \pstPlanePut[plane=xz,planecorr=normal](4,0,0){\Large\green\textbf{Vertical Text}}
\end{pspicture}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible

Thomas

```
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(2,3)
   \pstThreeDCoor[IIIDticks,xMin=-1,yMin=-1,zMin=-1,zMax=2]
   \pstPlanePut[plane=xz,planecorr=normal](4,0,0){\rput[l]{30}(0,0){\Large\green\textbf{Vertical Text}}}
   \pstPlanePut[plane=xz,planecorr=normal](4,0,0){\rput[l]{60}(0,0){\Large\blue\textbf{Vertical Text}}}
   \pstPlanePut[plane=xz,planecorr=normal](4,0,0){\rput[l]{90}(0,0){\Large\magenta\textbf{Vertical Text}}}
   \pstPlanePut[plane=xy,planecorr=normal](4,0,0){\rput[l]{-40}(0,0){\Large\magenta\textbf{Vertical Text}}}
   \pstPlanePut[plane=yz,planecorr=normal](0,1,0){\rput[l]{60}(0,0){\Large\blue\textbf{Vertical Text}}}
\end{pspicture}
```